# UpdateView gives blank/empty forms instead of previous data I edit

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, web

I'm using UpdateView to edit data using forms.

But, when I click edit button the forms are blank/empty without the previous data.

I even added {% with server.id as server_id %} {% with forms.id as edit_form %}
 in my index.html.. 
Does anoyone have anyclue what I am missing?

view.py-

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from DevOpsWeb.forms import HomeForm
from DevOpsWeb.models import serverlist
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from simple_search import search_filter
from django.db.models import Q
class HomeView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'serverlist.html'


    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    posts = serverlist.objects.all()

    if query:
        posts = serverlist.objects.filter(Q(ServerName__icontains=query) | Q(Owner__icontains=query) | Q(Project__icontains=query) | Q(Description__icontains=query) | Q(IP__icontains=query) | Q(ILO__icontains=query) | Q(Rack__icontains=query))
    else:
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()
    args = {'form' : form, 'posts' : posts}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def post(self,request):
    form = HomeForm(request.POST)
    posts = serverlist.objects.all()



    if form.is_valid(): # Checks if validation of the forms passed
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        #if not form.cleaned_data['ServerName']:
        #post.servername = " "
        post.save()
        #text = form.cleaned_data['ServerName']
        form = HomeForm()
        return redirect('serverlist')
args = {'form': form,  'text' : text}
return render(request, self.template_name,args)


class PostDelete(DeleteView):
    model = serverlist
    success_url = reverse_lazy('serverlist')

class PostEdit(UpdateView):
    model = serverlist
    #post = serverlist.objetcs.get(server_id=server_id)
    fields = ['ServerName','Owner','Project','Description','IP','ILO','Rack','Status']
    success_url=reverse_lazy('serverlist')
```

urls.py -

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from DevOpsWeb.views import HomeView
from DevOpsWeb.views import PostDelete
from DevOpsWeb.views import PostEdit
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='serverlist'),

     url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
     #DevOpsWeb:8000/Delete/
     url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDelete.as_view(), name="delete_post"),
     url(r'^django_popup_view_field/', include('django_popup_view_field.urls', namespace="django_popup_view_field")),
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     #DevOpsWeb:8000/edit/
     url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostEdit.as_view(), name="edit_post"),
]
```

forms.py -

```
from django import forms
from DevOpsWeb.models import serverlist


class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ServerName = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length = 30,required=False)
    Owner = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,required=False)
    Project = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    Description = forms.CharField(max_length = 255,required=False)
    IP = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    ILO = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    Rack = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    Status = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = serverlist
        fields = ('ServerName' ,'Owner','Project','Description','IP','ILO','Rack','Status',)

class AutoCompleteModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    widget = forms.TextInput
def clean(self, value):
    value = super(AutoCompleteModelChoiceField, self).clean(value)
    return value


class serverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    hotel = AutoCompleteModelChoiceField(queryset=serverlist.objects.all())
```

index.html (The part with the edit button)-

```
                {% for server in posts %}


        <tr>
          <div class ="server">
            <td></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.ServerName }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.Owner }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.Project }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.Description }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.IP }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.ILO }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ server.Rack }}</center></td>
            <td><h4><span class="badge badge-success">{{ server.Status }}</span></h4></td></center>

            <td>

&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" href="#delete-server-{{server.id}}"
             data-target="#Del{{server.id}}">Delete <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>&nbsp
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#edit-server-{{server.id}}"
             data-target="#Edit{{server.id}}"> &nbsp&nbspEdit&nbsp           <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
&nbsp






                        <div id ="Del{{server.id}}" class="modal fade" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" id="delete-server-{{server.id}}">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="{% url 'delete_post' server.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                                            <h6>Are you sure you want to delete {{ server.ServerName }}?</h6>
                                                <br>
                                            <center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" value="Confirm"/>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></center>

                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>


                        </div>
            </div>




            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" id="Edit{{server.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Server <b>{{ server.ServerName }}</b> </h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                        </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                                                    {% with server.id as server_id %}
                                                                    {% with forms.id as edit_form %}

                                <form action="{% url 'edit_post' server_id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                                    <!--<center>    {{ form.as_p }} </center> -->
                                    {% for field in form %}
                                        <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                            {{ field.errors }}
                                            <!-- {{ field.label_tag }} -->
                                            <small><b>{{ field.html_name }}<p align="left"></b> {{ field }}</small> </p>

                                            {% if field.help_text %}
                                                <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                                            {% endif %}
                                      </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="wrapper">
                            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                            <h2><button type="submit" class="save btn btn-success btn-lg">Confirm</button></h2>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                                <h2><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></h2>
                     </div>
                </form>
                {% endwith %}
                {% endwith %}
            </td>
                </div>
        </tr>
                {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</h5>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're a few problems in your example.

## First, you're not copying state over.

Right now, each of the forms you create has its value set to `None`, every time. This means your inputs will always be empty. Your current approach really needs to either replace the `form` instances and manually create `<input` tags or be re-thought with the [modelforms paradigm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/) in mind.

## Second, you don't have valid markup.

This will break most browsers. For example, you have

```
<small><b>{{ field.html_name }}<p align="left"></b> {{ field }}</small> </p>
```

This should be:

```
 <small><b>{{ field.html_name }}</b></small> <p align="left">{{ field }} </p>
```

Notice how the tags are now balanced? Or, even better:

```
 <small>
   <strong>{{ field.html_name }}</strong>
 </small>
 <p align="left">{{ field }}</p>
```

Now you can clearly see how the tags are supposed to be structured, making it much easier to diagnose any problems.

## Third, you're using outdated tags.

`<center>` hasn't been a valid node since HTML 4. `<b>` is ill-advised. Use `<strong>` instead.

## Forth, you have invalid character sequences.

`&nbsp&nbsp` should be `&nbsp;&nbsp;`

## Finally, you also have debug code littered throughout.

This offers you little compared to what you already have, and it risks breaking things:

```
<!--<center>    {{ form.as_p }} </center> -->
```

Comment: That's amazing.
Amazing answer.. so many things I need to fix and I will do it.
But the forms issue.. that's what I don't get!!
I wrote forms[post.id] = HomeForm(instance=post)

Comment: Can you give me the lines I need to change in the index and forms?